# RESOLVED - Rcpp is returning an error in Vector.h on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: r, rcpp

### tl;dr on the solution: this error apparently gets flagged on Big Sur using XCode CL tools when you use CharacterVector.push_back() inappropriately. I commented out an offending line, and it promptly stopped throwing the error!

I'm currently working on using Rcpp to write a C++ function for R using Rcpp::sourceCpp("FilePathName"), and it's returning a weird error.

> Library/FrameWorks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Vector.h
>
> Line 5: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string')

[image: Line 5: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string')]

I've tried running the gamut on updating XCode, gfortran, R, & Rcpp, clearing .R/Environ & .R/MakeVars, and manually editing .R/MakeVars to avoid using clang, but I can't seem to get past this one weird error. I think it has something to do with the update to Big Sur, seeing as that seems to cause some weirdness from time to time.

Any insight as to how best to proceed? For now I'm just trawling through various articles and documentation pieces to find another instance of this error, but so far I've had no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I am not a macOS user myself so can you maybe post in r-sig-mac and see if someone can confirm?  As far as we know, we're "in the green" on all official CRAN platforms but I believe they are more conservative on macOS upgrade.  Did this work previously?  Can you build other (simple) Rcpp packages from source?

Comment: I've had some success running Rcpp stuff on other people's machines before, but this is my first time running it on my machine. I've had some success with other, simpler printing functions a la hello world, so I'm confident it's a mix of user error and Big Sur weirdness, but I can't seem to figure out how this kind of issue would come about to debug it, given that it's throwing the error from Vector.h.

Comment: I guess you have the seen the guides by @coatless and others, I can't offer much else, sadly.

Comment: I appreciate the help very much regardless!

Comment: The error indicates an issue with initialization of a string. Check your program to take note of std::string usage

Comment: @Onyambu, I took a sweep back through the file that's giving me the issue, and I'm adding this for clarity. There are no uses of std::string in my code, nor are there any in the non Rcpp, std function I use. Further, when I check the specific file and line given by the error message, it shows a commented line, not an initialization.

Comment: Did you use `char` anywhere? Do you have a variable that stores character, string in your program?

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, all of it is built around using Rcpp's CharacterVector data type, but I'm not sure how that ends up throwing an error in a wildly different section of code, especially given that I had prior issues with declaring variables that got flagged by debug tools already, and it's only now that they're dealt with that I'm getting this error.

Comment: If you write a very simple function in R `Rcpp::cppFunction(code = 'void test() { Rcpp::CharacterVector cv(1); }')`, does this also error for you?

Comment: @Onyambu that is all widely used machinery to auto-translate from R character values to C++, and has been used happily for well over a decade; just glance at the over 2k questions for tag `rcpp` here.  But macOS sometimes does things to the setup, compiler, headers, ... that throws a spanner.

Comment: As well as our all-time basic `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")`.

Comment: Just ran through both those examples, and they're working fine. I suspect something weird happened with some macOS C++ library routing or the like, at this point, and I'll keep updating this thread as I test out different things. I really appreciate the help with this!

Comment: An update on this: see above for how I resolved the problem ultimately, it was a simple code error on my part that returned a weird error message, after all. Thank you so much for the help!